# Does Tfs "Check-out lock" consume more resources and slow down VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, resharper, tfvc

I recently joined to a team at my work that uses "**Check-out lock**" in TFS.

**[Check-out lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/understand-lock-types?view=vsts)** means that none of the team members can edit a file while it's checked-out in other team member's computer.

This is the first time I use that kind of lock, usually I work on projects without any locks and I notice that my **VS(2015)** and my team mates is extremely slow, especially when doing actions such as: adding a new file, get latest version(visual studio is not responding for a while) and writing code.

I recently installed **Resharper**(VS was slow before I installed it) and under it Performance Guide it marked:
**Source control plug-in in use** as a affecting performance.

Is there a way to prove my concern so my TL will accept my opinion and remove this lock type?

Comment: Not sure if the lock type will slow down visual studio but a slow tfs server or slow network will slow down visual studio.  Everytime you open a new file it calls the tfs server and checks if it is locked and tries to check it out.

Comment: of course if you are using GIT with TFS you wont see any delay because this happens on the same machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using exclusive checkouts with TFVC each time you start editing a file, Visual Studio will need to make a server roundtrip to check for the lock status of the file on the server and subsequently lock it. If the TFS server is slow or far away this can take a while. It's likely this team has also configured "Get latest on checkout" which will do a couple of extra round trips.

When adding a file to the solution the problem is aggravated, as Visual Studio will need to lock the project file and the file being added. In case of a new form or control this often results in the creation of multiple files.

In 2012 TFS has introduced a new workspace type of TFVC, the *local workspace*. This type doesn't support exclusive checkout and keeps edit state locally. As such it's much faster, works better when you're not always connected and generally has much better performance (up to a certain size of workspace). This workspace type is the default workspace type for recent versions of TFS.

The perf issues of your colleagues don't seem to be directly related to the TFVC workspace type nor the use of exclusive checkout though. The warning from Resharper is simply that you have *any* source control integration enabled:

> Source Control | Plug-in Selection: select None for the source control plug-in. This will turn off Git or another VCS provider and improve overall performance.

When using TFVC, only actions that cause server interaction will be slowed down due to the additional network roundtrips. Normal work shouldn't be negatively impacted by it. This suggests your colleagues have other issues on his machine or with the solution they're using. It's likely caused by some extension or due to the large project size. Visual Studio 2015 is the first version of Visual Studio that depends on Roslyn for compilation and it has its issues. In Visual Studio 2017 (especially in 15.6 and later) performance issues have been drastically reduced.

Should you want to convince your boss to stop doing exclusive checkouts, I have some other ammo for you:

- Exclusive checkouts were added to TFVC in order to support the older workflows in Source Safe and to prevent issues with merging binary files.
- Exclusive checkouts have been discouraged even in version 2005.
- Local Workspaces which were introduced in 2012 removed support for Exclusive checkout completely.
- The new defacto standard source control mechanism in TFS and VSTS is Git. It has no concept of exclusive checkouts due to its distributed nature.
- Exclusive locking is an indicator of other issues in the codebase and the collaboration patterns of the team in many cases.
- If the concern is to remove merge conflicts, get better at merging.

Your team is likely used to the fact that they never have to merge things as long as they lock everything. It causes different frustrations. Some perf impact is one of them. But not the perf impact you're describing.

Comment: @OffirPe'er That's almost always because they don't merge frequently enough. Branches should be divergent for as short a period of time as possible. The general rule is, "The longer it's been since you merged, the more painful the merge is going to be."